# HttpClient Head request memory exception PCL

Tags: out-of-memory, httpclient, portable-class-library, head

Hi people i'm trying to do a head request to get the content-length of the file (it's big >= 200MB) and simple just throw me an exception saying "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown." since it's a HEAD method this shouldn't be a problem right?

Here is my code:

```
   using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                    {
                        RequestUri = new Uri(streamLink.StreamLink),
                        Method = HttpMethod.Head
                    })
                    {
                        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                        {
                            var restatus = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
                            if (restatus)
                            {
                                var filesize = ConvertBytesToMegabytes(response.Content.Headers.ContentLength);
                                CalculateStreamQuality(filesize, streamLink, runtime);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the SendAsync with the completion option parameter set to: **HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead** - this will enable the SendAsync method to complete without trying to allocate a buffer to hold the (non-existent data payload).

Update your code to use the following:

```
using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
{ 
...
}
```